# How to set configuration parameters using an array table?

Tags: c++

Following situation: I have an array with some constant values, which represent ranges.
A range is always between two values in the array, e.g.: 10 - 20 = range1
20-30 = range2 and so on...

```
const int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
```

With a Search function, I search for the number(val) between those ranges in arr[] and return the range index where val was found.
For example: if val = 15 → return value would be 1
             if val = 33 → return value would be 3

```
int Search(const int arr[], int n, int val)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < n) {
        if (val > arr[i])
            ++i;
        else
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

OK, this works out so far...

Now following problem:
I have some parameters let's call them x, y, z which are simple integers and they depend on the value of val.
The parameter values for x, y, z I know already before compilation, of course they are different for every range.
How can I now set x, y and z using the range index?
How can I make an array for example with the constant parameter values for x, y, z and set them depending on the returned range index? Or should it be a struct?
How would that look like...?

Thx

Comment: So far what i understand from the problem statement is that you'll initially have some values for x,y,z variables (dependant on val) and based on the index returned you again want to set the values for x,y,z values. Let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: you did understand my question. what you wrote is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hold the parameters for each range in a `struct`:

```
struct range_parameters {
    int x;
    int y;
    // etc
}
```

And keep all these structs in a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<range_parameters> params;
```

Adding the data would be done like this:

```
range_parameters params_for_range_1;
params_for_range_1.x = 1;
params_for_range_1.y = 2;

params[0] = params_for_range_1;
```

So finally you can access the parameters for range `n` as `params[n-1]`.

Comment: Thx! I will use an array of structs instead of std::vector, because i'm working on a small hardware.